# Allow user via SafeCracker to choose a member with that member then assigned editorial rights to the entry

Tags: safecracker, solspace-user

I'm trying to build a permissions / approval based app using EE.

Effectively user's are assigned trainers. Once the user has passed a skill they login and via SafeCracker would request to be approved for that skill. The request process would also include the name of the trainer.

In the CP I would then like the trainer to be assigned access privileges to the entry so that they could approve or disapprove it.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? I do have Solspace User which seems to have  multi author functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: User's multi-author functionality doesn't give any extra EE permissions to additional members for a given entry. It's simply a feature for building a list of members associated with an entry. Eg. a sports team, or authors of a scientific journal.

Comment: Thanks Solspace, I appreciate your comment. Any suggestions on how I may tackle this? Is there a way I can automate an email to the trainer so they can log in and search for the user's entry and approve it?

Comment: Can't you natively set EE member group permissions to allow "trainer" members to be able to edit other member's entries, as well as give access to this "Requests" channel?

Comment: Hi Solspace, yep that would work. The only problem is there will be several thousands of users regularly making these requests and I need a way to route a request effectively to the correct trainer and I need the trainer to change the status to open before they can appear on the users' account.

Comment: Not a Solspace add-on-related idea, but maybe users could submit "request entries" through SafeCracker/Channel Form and set the entry author to the appropriate trainer? Then these trainers would just have to look for these entries in which they are the author, and approve/disapprove (CP or front-end).

Comment: That sounds like something that might work. How would a user make a "request entry"? Do you mean simply have them make an "anonymous" entry for that channel and somehow assign the author. How would they assign an author?

Comment: I just did a search for "email smtp settings" on your site and I found a link to this page:http://www.solspace.com/blog/entry/entry_notifications_3.0_released_software_gets_lonely_too/

Comment: I don't know your project in detail but based on your comment: "_Once the user has passed a skill they login and via SafeCracker would request to be approved for that skill._", I assumed users create entries in some channel that you might have called "Requests" or something along those lines. I think SafeCracker/Channel Form has the ability to set an author. Also, that blog post is **5 years old** (interestingly, as of today); that add-on has been discontinued a long time ago.

Comment: That's it in a nutshell. I looked into the option of setting the member ID and Channel Form does have something but it seems to be for users that posting when not logged in: 
"In order to allow logged out users to use the entry form, you must specify a member_id which will be used as the author of the entry." Do you think I can use that even if the user is logged in to override it?